# On back orders, how do I get only items that have a remaining quantity to print on the Advanced PDF?

Tags: templates, pdf, netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

I created a new Advanced PDF/HTML for back orders that have some items that have shipped, and some items still open with a future ship date. When I print the pdf, it shows the items that have already shipped as a quantity of zero. How do I tell the system to only print line items that have a quantity greater than zero?

````
<#if record.item?has_content>  
<table class="classic-table" style="width: 100%; margin-top:10px;"><!-- start items --><#list record.item as lineItem><#if lineItem_index==0><tr>
    <th class="column-sub-title" colspan="5">Item Code</th>
    <th class="column-sub-title" colspan="7">${lineItem.item@label}</th>
    <th class="column-sub-title" colspan="6">${lineItem.description@label}</th>
    <th class="column-sub-title" colspan="4">Quantity</th>
    <th class="column-sub-title" colspan="3">${lineItem.rate@label}</th>
    <th class="column-sub-title" colspan="3">${lineItem.amount@label}</th>
    </tr></#if>
       <tr>
    <td class="column-data" colspan="5">${lineItem.custcol_htd_item_id}</td>
    <td class="column-data" colspan="7">${lineItem.item}</td>
    <td class="column-data" colspan="6">${lineItem.description}</td>
    <td class="column-data" colspan="4">${lineItem.custcol_htd_quantity_remaining}</td>
    <td class="column-data" colspan="3">${lineItem.custcol_unbilled_unit_price}</td>
    <td class="column-data" colspan="3">${lineItem.custcol_htd_dollar_amt_remaining}</td>
    </tr>
    </#list><!-- end items -->```
````

Comment: what transaction are you working on?

Comment: @vVinceth Sales orders

Comment: The Picking ticket related to the sales order already does this, it will only print the items that still need to be fulfilled/shipped. I would like it to do a similar process with the sales order.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Picking Ticket on Sales Orders for that.

Another way is to add an if statement like the following:
https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_directive_if.html

```
    <#if lineItem.custcol_htd_quantity_remaining>0> 
    <tr>
           <td class="column-data" colspan="5">${lineItem.custcol_htd_item_id}</td>
           <td class="column-data" colspan="7">${lineItem.item}</td>
           <td class="column-data" colspan="6">${lineItem.description}</td>
           <td class="column-data" colspan="4">${lineItem.custcol_htd_quantity_remaining}</td>
           <td class="column-data" colspan="3">${lineItem.custcol_unbilled_unit_price}</td>
           <td class="column-data" colspan="3">${lineItem.custcol_htd_dollar_amt_remaining}</td>
    </tr>
    </#if>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Gustavo, that pretty much worked except instead of using the greater than ">" symbol, I used "gt" and that did the trick. 
The other thing I had to change was my custom body field "htd_quantity_remaining" to identify as an integer, I originally had it saved as free-form text which wouldn't work in that formula.

If anyone else is have problems with printing accurate information for back orders, i.e. subtotal and total of dollar amount still open on the order vs. the original dollar amount of the SO, I was finally able to work through a solution.

First, you'll need to create a saved search to total up the subtotal of all invoices related to that sales order. In our industry, some sales orders will have 3-4 invoices related to it. GO TO:

1. Hover over reports, select "new search"
2. Criteria tab, filter sub menu select:

   - Type: is invoice
   - Main Line: is True (yes)

   Results tab select:

   - Document Number
   - Subtotal amount w/ summary type as "sum"

   Available Filters tab select:

   - Created From: Internal ID w/ "show in filter region" selected (yes)
3. Use that saved search to create a custom body field labeled as "Amount Billed To-Date (subtotal)"
4. Create another custom body field labeled "Amount Unbilled (subtotal)" and under the Validating and Default tab, select formula. Set formula to: Subtotal - amount billed to-date
5. Use the custom body field "Amount Unbilled (subtotal)" as the new subtotal on the advanced pdf/html for any back orders. I created an entire new sales order form for back orders, but I'm sure there is a way to include this info on the default Sales Order pdf by using an IF-ELSE formula.

These instructions assume you somewhat know how to work with Netsuite coding, if you need further explanation let me know.